# unusual rotation of particle

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I was following Andrew Price's tutorial on making dynamic rain. I followed the tutorial till a point where I found that there's something wrong with my particle settings....
This is what Andrew did
[image: this is what Andrew did]
This is what I got
[image: and this is what I got. Do notice the horizontal particles.]

My particles aren't dying like his. So please help me friends. I can't get his starter file also as there's something wrong with it :(
Here are some pics about my particles setup :
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what is going wrong, you need to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have the full screenshot, so can't see if you've set the particles to end at the same time or not. right hand corner of the screen, in particle settings, make sure you have the particle system start/end values set correctly, as well as the 'life' of the particles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a *Collision* in the physics panel of the plane and check *Kill Particles*